Query_all_packages Permission Rejected on Play Console - How to Resolve?
My request for the Query_all_packages permission was rejected on the Play Console. Is there another solution? I want the app to open for confirmation after pressing the Open App button, but the code works on older phones, yet it doesn't work on devices running Android 11 and above.
I've tried most of the code, but I couldn't solve the issue related to the permissions. I've been struggling with this for 3 days
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.testing.brctestingcommunity">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/brctesting"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/brctesting"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginRegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AddAppActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AppDetailActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".WebLinkActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity" />

        <!-- UserAppsActivity Eklendi -->
        <activity
            android:name=".UserAppsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrcTestingCommunity" />


        <activity android:name=".PoliciesActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RefundPolicyActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ShippingPolicyActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TermsConditionsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PrivacyPolicyActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".StepsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GuideActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>


package com.testing.brctestingcommunity

import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.CenterCrop
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RoundedCorners
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class AppDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webLinkLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    private lateinit var feedbackLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    private lateinit var webLinkButton: Button
    private lateinit var androidLinkButton: Button
    private lateinit var countdownTextView: TextView
    private val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private var shouldShowFeedbackPopup: Boolean = false
    private var shouldShowOpenAppPopup: Boolean = false
    private var feedbackGiven: Boolean = false
    private var pointsAwardedForFeedback: Boolean = false // Kullanıcının geri bildirim puanı alıp almadığını kontrol eder
    private val feedbackPoints = 5
    private val webLinkPoints = 5 // WebLink için verilecek puan

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_detail)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.app_details)

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }

        loadDataFromIntent(intent)

        webLinkButton = findViewById(R.id.web_link_button)
        androidLinkButton = findViewById(R.id.android_link_button)
        countdownTextView = findViewById(R.id.countdown_text_view) // Geri sayım için TextView

        webLinkLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                addPointsToUser(webLinkPoints)
                Toast.makeText(this, "You earned $webLinkPoints points!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                webLinkButton.visibility = View.GONE // WebLink butonunu gizle
                saveWebLinkStatusToFirestore()
            }
        }

        feedbackLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { _ ->
            if (feedbackGiven && !pointsAwardedForFeedback) {
                addPointsToUser(feedbackPoints)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you for your feedback! You earned $feedbackPoints points.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                pointsAwardedForFeedback = true
                saveFeedbackGivenStatusToFirestore()
                saveLastInteractionTime() // Zaman damgasını kaydet
                startCountdown(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 24 saatlik geri sayım başlat
                androidLinkButton.visibility = View.GONE // Butonu gizle
                countdownTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE // Geri sayım göster
            }
        }

        webLinkButton.setOnClickListener {
            val webLink = intent.getStringExtra("webLink")
            if (!webLink.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                openLinkInWebView(webLink)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_web_link_provided), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        androidLinkButton.setOnClickListener {
            val androidLink = intent.getStringExtra("androidLink")
            if (!androidLink.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                shouldShowOpenAppPopup = true
                shouldShowFeedbackPopup = true
                openPlayStoreLink(androidLink)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_android_link_provided), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        // Buton durumlarını kontrol et
        checkButtonVisibility()

        checkAndInitializeUser()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if (shouldShowOpenAppPopup) {
            showOpenAppPopup()
            shouldShowOpenAppPopup = false
        } else if (shouldShowFeedbackPopup) {
            showFeedbackPopup()
            shouldShowFeedbackPopup = false
        }

        // Butonların görünürlüğünü her geri dönüşte kontrol edin
        checkButtonVisibility()
    }

    private fun loadDataFromIntent(intent: Intent) {
        val appLogo: ShapeableImageView = findViewById(R.id.app_logo)
        val appName: TextView = findViewById(R.id.app_name)
        val developerName: TextView = findViewById(R.id.developer_name)
        val postDate: TextView = findViewById(R.id.post_date)
        val credits: TextView = findViewById(R.id.credits)
        val appDescription: TextView = findViewById(R.id.app_description)

        val logoUrl = intent.getStringExtra("logoUrl")
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val developer = intent.getStringExtra("developer")
        val date = intent.getStringExtra("date")
        val creditsValue = intent.getIntExtra("credits", 0)
        val description = intent.getStringExtra("description")

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(logoUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions().transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(16)))
            .into(appLogo)

        appName.text = name
        developerName.text = developer
        postDate.text = getString(R.string.posted_on, date)
        credits.text = getString(R.string.credits, creditsValue)
        appDescription.text = description
    }

    private fun openLinkInWebView(url: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, WebLinkActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("url", url)
            putExtra("logoUrl", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("logoUrl"))
            putExtra("name", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("name"))
            putExtra("developer", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("developer"))
            putExtra("date", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("date"))
            putExtra("credits", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getIntExtra("credits", 0))
            putExtra("description", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("description"))
            putExtra("webLink", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("webLink"))
            putExtra("androidLink", this@AppDetailActivity.intent.getStringExtra("androidLink"))
        }
        webLinkLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    private fun openPlayStoreLink(url: String) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            }
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "Play Store link opened: $url")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Play Store link could not be opened: $url", e)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to open the Play Store link.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun checkButtonVisibility() {
        val webLink = intent.getStringExtra("webLink")
        val androidLink = intent.getStringExtra("androidLink")

        if (userId != null) {
            val userRef = db.collection("users").document(userId)

            userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document.exists()) {
                    val earnedUrls = document.get("earnedUrls") as? List<*>
                    if (earnedUrls != null && earnedUrls.contains(webLink)) {
                        webLinkButton.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        webLinkButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }

                    val feedbackGivenForUrls = document.get("feedbackGivenForUrls") as? List<*>
                    val lastInteractionTime = document.getLong("lastInteractionTime") ?: 0L
                    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    val elapsedTime = currentTime - lastInteractionTime

                    if (feedbackGivenForUrls != null && feedbackGivenForUrls.contains(androidLink)) {
                        if (elapsedTime < 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
                            androidLinkButton.visibility = View.GONE
                            countdownTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            startCountdown(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - elapsedTime)
                        } else {
                            androidLinkButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            countdownTextView.visibility = View.GONE
                        }
                    } else {
                        androidLinkButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        countdownTextView.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Failed to check button visibility: $e")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun extractPackageNameFromUrl(url: String): String? {
        return try {
            val uri = Uri.parse(url)
            uri.getQueryParameter("id") ?: uri.lastPathSegment.also {
                Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "Extracted package name: $it")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Failed to extract package name from URL: $url", e)
            null
        }
    }

    private fun openInstalledApp(packageName: String) {
        Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "Trying to open the app: $packageName")
        try {
            val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
            if (intent != null) {
                startActivity(intent)
                Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "App opened: $packageName")
            } else {
                Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "App not found: $packageName")
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "App is not installed or you are not part of the test group. Make sure you are signed in with the correct Google account.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Error while trying to open the app: $packageName", e)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to open the app due to an error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun showOpenAppPopup() {
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout) // Burada doğru layout dosyasını kullanın
        val openAppButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.openAppButton)

        openAppButton.setOnClickListener {
            val androidLink = intent.getStringExtra("androidLink")
            if (!androidLink.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val appPackageName = extractPackageNameFromUrl(androidLink)
                if (!appPackageName.isNullOrEmpty() && isAppInstalled(appPackageName)) {
                    openInstalledApp(appPackageName)
                    shouldShowFeedbackPopup = true
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.app_not_installed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun showFeedbackPopup() {
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_feedback_layout)
        val feedbackButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.feedbackButton)

        feedbackButton.setOnClickListener {
            val androidLink = intent.getStringExtra("androidLink")
            if (!androidLink.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val appPackageName = extractPackageNameFromUrl(androidLink)
                if (!appPackageName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    feedbackGiven = true // Mark as feedback given before redirecting
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName"))
                    feedbackLauncher.launch(intent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid app link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No app link provided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun isAppInstalled(packageName: String): Boolean {
        return try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
            Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "App is installed: $packageName")
            true
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "App is not installed: $packageName")
            false
        }
    }

    private fun addPointsToUser(points: Int) {
        userId?.let { uid ->
            val userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
            userRef.update("points", FieldValue.increment(points.toLong()))
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "$points points added to user.")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Error adding points: ", e)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to add points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
        }
    }

    private fun saveFeedbackGivenStatusToFirestore() {
        userId?.let { uid ->
            val androidLink = intent.getStringExtra("androidLink")
            if (androidLink != null) {
                val userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
                userRef.update("feedbackGivenForUrls", FieldValue.arrayUnion(androidLink))
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "Feedback given status saved for $androidLink.")
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Error saving feedback given status: $androidLink", e)
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveWebLinkStatusToFirestore() {
        userId?.let { uid ->
            val webLink = intent.getStringExtra("webLink")
            if (webLink != null) {
                val userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
                userRef.update("earnedUrls", FieldValue.arrayUnion(webLink))
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "WebLink status saved for $webLink.")
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Error saving WebLink status: $webLink", e)
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveLastInteractionTime() {
        userId?.let { uid ->
            val userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
            userRef.update("lastInteractionTime", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "Last interaction time saved.")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Error saving last interaction time: ", e)
                }
        }
    }

    private fun startCountdown(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        val countdownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(millisUntilFinished, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                val hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)
                val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60
                val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60
                val timeFormatted = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
                countdownTextView.text = "Button will be active in: $timeFormatted"
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                countdownTextView.visibility = View.GONE
                androidLinkButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
        countdownTimer.start()
    }

    private fun checkAndInitializeUser() {
        val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        if (userId != null) {
            val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(userId)
            userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (!document.exists()) {
                    initializeUserInFirestore(userId) // Eğer kullanıcı Firestore'da yoksa başlat
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Error checking user in Firestore: $userId", e)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initializeUserInFirestore(userId: String) {
        val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(userId)
        val userData = hashMapOf(
            "points" to 0,
            "earnedUrls" to emptyList<String>(),
            "feedbackGivenForUrls" to emptyList<String>(),
            "lastInteractionTime" to 0L
        )

        userRef.set(userData)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("AppDetailActivity", "User initialized in Firestore: $userId")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("AppDetailActivity", "Failed to initialize user in Firestore: $userId", e)
            }
    }
}



Why are you requesting that permission? Is it for the getLaunchIntentForPackage() calls, or for something else? "yet it doesn't work on devices running Android 11 and above" -- can you please explain in detail what "doesn't work" means in this case?

Google have made it very clear that QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES is an exceptional case and will only be granted if your app is of a certain type like an app launcher.
I work at a company where we made heavy use of package management and to support Android 11 we had to accept some changes and change our way of doing things such as:

For package names which we know we are going to have to support, add them to the manifest (<queries> section), then you can query them as you did on earlier versions of Android
For arbitrary packages which we don't necessarily know the names of at build time, we have to accept that there's no way to detect if the package is installed on the device or not. We just show more generic errors to the users like "we couldn't launch the app, please check if it is installed" etc
You can still launch an app even if you can't query the package. But you have to know the Activity Class you want to launch. We had to develop a solution where the server sends us the name of the Activity Class for a particular app. You do this by intent.setClassName(...) We only use this solution for packages where we don't know the package name at build time (otherwise we could put them in the manifest and avoid this complexity)


There are currently processes that can perform this operation on version 14. I tested it on a different application, and they are able to run multiple unknown applications

@TİESTO Can you share what the name of that application is? There are a few possibilities, (a) it may be an old application with a targetSdkVersion of 29 or lower, (b) it may have been granted the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, (c) they may already have the Activity Class stored in the app or have that app's package name in their manifest, (d) it may be a "force-queryable" application (these are usually system-level applications, which can be queried from anywhere)

"The application is in the testing phase, but you can check it out. It is currently compatible with all versions and is working. You can join the group and download it here: https://groups.google.com/g/testnetbrc https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.testing.brctestingcommunity"

I solved the problem. When I used intent, there was no time problem. I got approval from Play Console. After parsing the package name of the applications in the application and registering it in Firebase, I added the manifest as intent. The problem was solved. A restriction was imposed.

Not sure what you mean unfortunately. Did you get the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission or not? When you used the intent, did you query the Activity Class Name yourself using a manifest entry, or did you hard-code it? I am not sure what you mean by "there was no time problem" or "I added the manifest as intent" or "a restriction was imposed" unfortunately.
